# Alternative to number_format() that will erase `.00` but will leave `.5` or `.567`

Tags: php

I have numbers that look like this:

```
    175.0000
    185.0000
    195.0000
    205.0000
    13.0000
    15.0000
```

But I also have numbers that look like this:

```
    10.5000
    7.5000
```

The function `number_format()` is not cutting it because, if I set it to leave `1` decimal place, it will leave the `.0` in the numbers that aren't `7.5` or `10.5`.

Is there a function that will only display a decimal point if it is greater than `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the number with its integer value to check the number of decimal you need:

```
$num = 7.0;
echo number_format($num, ($num == (int)$num) ? 0 : 1);
$num = 7.5;
echo number_format($num, ($num == (int)$num) ? 0 : 1);
```

Output:

```
7
7.5
```

A shorter version *only if* you need 1 decimal:

```
echo number_format($num, $num != (int)$num); // bool to int = 0 or 1.
```

Another way is to use `rtrim()` twice: first for zéros, second for dot:

```
echo rtrim(rtrim(number_format($num, 3), '0'),'.');
```

Comment: But this limits the number to 1 decimal. With a longer decimal point it will round up. Is there a way for this to be more dynamic? For example to handle numbers like `75.33100 -> 75.331` as well as `75.30000 -> 75.3` and of course `75.0000 -> 75`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very experienced with php but I found this

```
echo 13.00 + 0; //gives you 13
echo '125.00' + 0; //gives you 125
echo 76.5 + 0; //gives you 76.5
```

[PHP Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$arr=[175.0000, 185.0000, 195.0000, 205.0000, 13.0000, 15.0000, 10.5000, 7.5000 ];
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo round($value,2)."\n";
}
```

This will work for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$a =  Array("13.0000",
            "15.0000",
            "10.5000",
            "7.5000");

$a = preg_replace('/0+$/', "", $a);
$a = preg_replace('/[.]$/', "", $a);
```

Result = 13, 15, 10.5, 7.5

Answer (score 0):

This isn't in PHP, but is the general algorithm.

There are several ways to do this:

```
if unformattedNumber % 1 == unformattedNumber:
    formattedNumber = number_format(unformattedNumber)
else:
    formattedNumber = number_format(unformattedNumber, 1)
```

or

```
formattedNumber = number_format(unformattedNumber, 1)
if formattedNumber[-1] == 0:
    formattedNumber = number_format(formattedNumber)
```